# Deploy symfony2 website in windows XP local server

Tags: symfony, windows-xp

I developed a website using Symfony2. In my local server everything is just fine. But when I deployed it to another Windows XP Home Edition local server, everything works but upload images to a local folder inside web folder. I checked the permissions and I think everything is OK.

The error, when I tried to upload an image is seems to be related with permissions.

My question is, what are the users I must give permissions in Windows XP, so I could upload images through the web application? Best regards....Yanet

Comment: this might help. https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/server-permissions.htm

Comment: Windows XP is oit of support